# PHP organise rows of the same values

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving data from sql server and then present them in an organised way.
I have an array of object like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 1
        [controller] => Cato
        [controller_method] => edit
        [http_method] => post
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 1
        [controller] => Cato
        [controller_method] => edit
        [http_method] => get
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 1
        [controller] => Cato
        [controller_method] => create
        [http_method] => post
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 1
        [controller] => Cato
        [controller_method] => create
        [http_method] => get
    )
)
```

Somehow I need to convert to things like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [controller] => controller1,
        [controller_methods] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [controller_method] => create,
                [http_methods] => Array (
                    [0] => get,
                    [1] => post
                )
            ),
            [0] => Array (
                [controller_method] => edit,
                [http_methods] => Array (
                    [0] => get,
                    [1] => post
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    [0] => Array(
        [controller] => controller2,
        [controller_methods] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [controller_method] => create,
                [http_methods] => Array (
                    [0] => get,
                    [1] => post
                )
            ),
            [0] => Array (
                [controller_method] => edit,
                [http_methods] => Array (
                    [0] => get,
                    [1] => post
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I always encounter things like this when working with php with sql db
Is there any convenient way to do this?

Comment: Where did `controller1` and `controller2` in the result data come from? They don't appear anywhere in the input. Also the two output arrays appear to be identical apart from this `controller` key, what is the logic you use to get from one format to the other?

Comment: I am only giving an example of that, actually the controller column varies. Each controller has many controller methods. Each controller method has many http_methods. I need to organise them.

Comment: So the input data actually only represents 1 controller?